# What is the range of values for CAP_PROP_GAIN in opencv2?

Tags: opencv

I'm using `OpenCV` to pull image frames from a web cam and for the most part it's working extremely well.
The challenge is that one of the requirements is that the operator be allowed to manually modify the gain setting, and I can't find any documentation to tell me the allowable range of values for the `cv2.CAP_PROP_GAIN` value.
I'm working with two cameras - one built-in to my laptop and other a cheapo I picked up at Best Buy.  When I call `VideoCapture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_GAIN)` on the two cameras, one returns 1.0 and the other returns 192.0.
What is the range of allowed values for `CAP_PROP_GAIN`?  1 to 1000?  0.0 to 1.0?  0 to 255?

Comment: Seems like it depends on the specific VideoIO backend and camera used. The documentation mentions: "Note: Each backend supports devices properties (cv::VideoCaptureProperties) in a different way or might not support any property at all."

Comment: Just as an example -- for DirectShow backend, this maps to `VideoProcAmp_Gain`, for which Microsoft documentation says: "Specifies the gain adjustment. Zero is normal. Positive values are brighter and negative values are darker. The range of values depends on the device."